# RE: Modifying bluetooth scan parameters via btmgmt

Tags: bluetooth, bluez

I have the same problem of @Hias about this topic:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/420978

The more interesting answer is:
"modify bluetooth kernel module, set any discoveryFilter using Bluez (i.e.: RSSI -127)."

The answer is not clear to me.
Where is the "bluetooth kernel module"?
That is, what is the directory?

In the output of this command:

```
sudo btmgmt --index 1 find
```

Between "hci1 type 7 discovering on" and "hci1 type 7 discovering off" there is a time of 11 seconds (I counted in mind).
How to change this time?

If --timer parameter is 5 for example, i must wait other six second to execute the command, otherwise it gives me the output of busy: 5+6=11

For business needs I need to extend the scan times through the btmgmt command (or its configuration file, if it exists) and not through similar commands, the watch command is too draining on the raspberrypi and does not respond to my goals.

Answer (score 1):

> The answer is not clear to me.
> Where is the "bluetooth kernel module"?
> That is, what is the directory?

You probably don't want to modify the kernel module. Unless you know C very well and have built kernel modules before, I would advise against it. Plus, modifying the kernel module would leave your program in an unusable state on anyone's computer unless they also patched their kernel the same way you did. That said, if you absolutely positively think that's the way to go, I'm assuming you're on raspbian, you ought to be able to just apt install linux-sources and then you'd go to the /usr/src/ directory and unpack the kernel from the tar archive found there. Then once you're finished editing the kernel you could compile a new kernel. Have a look over at the gentoo docs or linux-from-scratch pages for quick and easy ways to compile a kernel or a kernel module. Again, I would completely scrap the idea of messing with the kernel, but that's me.

For what you want to do with btmgmt, [there is a Python wrapper for btmgmt](https://pypi.org/project/btmgmt/) which would give you fine grain control over how you use that specific tool. With Python at your disposal, even if the btmgmt tool doesn't offer a specific feature that you are looking for, or you can't figure out how a specific feature works with it, you could build that in to your script yourself.